# Send sms from air application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

I have to send SMS through air application.
whenever user click on send button application send SMS to selected user.

can you please tell me how can i do this in my air application by using flex or .net.

Comment: i want to use this by either flex or .net...

Comment: this is not available for desktop air application..:(

Answer (score 2):

Reffer this link
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SMS_Texting_with_Flex_and_Air-12007.html
and 
https://sites.google.com/site/freesmsuk/send-free-sms-with-flex

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Game of Flex (available for both iOS and Android). Under Native extensions you'll find the code snippet for sending SMS using an URLRequest. Something like this:

```
<s:Button label="send" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('sms:125498964'))" />
```